# RF transmitter interference to a GE electric stove

Tags: rf, interference

I have a GE Stove with electronic controls which malfunction when I transmit 500 watts of RF on the 1.8 mhz Ham radio band. I suspect the transmitted RF is getting into the AC lines and causing the malfunction of the stove controls. Would an AC line filter installed at the AC supply box help the problem ? Any recommendations for a filter ? The stove draws 35 amps on each leg of a 220 vac 2-phase line.

Comment: Put the antenna on the roof and not under your bed.:)

Comment: @MarkoBuršič -- not much help with 500W @ 1.8MHz, I am afraid

Comment: Can you get us a wiring diagram for this balky stove?  Or a make/model for that matter?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the electronics work off L1 or L2 only while stove works off L1&2.  I might suggest MgZn ferrite snap-on choke on both L1&L2 as they will couple anyways at 2MHz.  See if the video CM choke on any old VGA cable will fit around AWG10copper wires. These are molded in plastic sleeves but micro-gap but be perfectly matched and clean as an experiment, or large torroid on Coax feed to reduce CM radiation near power lines that converts to differential voltage from mismatch at controller due to power supply not having adequate CM filter.

So yes a line filter on AC, CM choke torroid over RF coax or both. You might be using fairly large core coax and large RF connectors , so snap-on types may be more easily applied.

MnZn has the largest Mu of 3k to 5k, suitable for CM choke in low RF in  low MHz region like the reducing VGA radiation on 75 Ohm Dsub cable.  THis ferrite is non-conductive, while the low mu NiZc ferrite suitable for microwave is conductive with test probe using a DMM, due to Nickel content and bigger ferrous gaps between particles.

Comment: Hi Tony - thanks for the input- As you suggested I just tried to use an old video CM choke but the ID is too small for the stove AC line - just ordered snap-on Mix 31 (low RF freq) RF ferrites from DX engineering - and will try those before chasing down some suitable MnZn types with a 0.75 inch ID.

Comment: I just checked - "mix 31" ferrites are MnZn type so I shud be Ok at 1.8 Mhz.

Comment: One way to detect RF leakage is a series Schottky diode and RF cap and use a loop wire around the suspect cable during Tx and measure mV DC scale with DMM. This leakage may also suggest your antenna balun point is mismatched

Comment: BTW Steve Buscemi in The Boardwalk Empire is one of my fave actors

Comment: make a low power Tx mode with a return loss bridge to maximize return loss using same Sch Diode shunt cap to DMM Vdc mV to minimize on reflected power

Comment: Hi Agn Tony - Steve B. is a distant cousin - the family name comes from town in Sicily of same name so we are all related ..hihi.. tnx tip on RF sniffer..the transmitting 43 ft vertical is 6 feet from the AC drop wire to the house - I am amazed that the stove is the ONLY thing acting up at the moment. It's not RF "leakage", it's straight-away direct radiation into the AC line. AC feed to the stove is very accessible so I am hoping the ferrites will do the job.       Jay NY2NY - "EE since 64"....(retired)

Comment: Choke will raise the impedance then Y cap (plastic >=600V) to shunt the RF 0.022 to 0.047uF I recall to ground

Comment: Hi Tony - I added 2- 0.05mfd 600v plastic caps from each 125 v line to ground on the stove line in the main AC panel. RFI GONE !! was that easy - now running full RF power at 500w on 160m with no stove problem. Sometines the easiest fix is the best. I do have the Mix 31 cores on order and will add them to the AC feedline directly under the stove as an added precaution. Thx again for your help !!

Comment: glad to see it worked

Comment: final notes - added 3 Mix 31 snap-on cores from DX engineering and not a trace of problem with full power out.

Comment: the chokes raise impedance to reduce drawing current from antenna. I might suggest a good ground plane around antenna  with radial flatwire

Comment: @JayBuscemi -- one long-term suggestion would be to swap the two caps in the panel for X1 or X2 rated 250VAC units of the same value -- (it's really not clear *what* sense Article 460 makes when applied to small capacitors, but a Class X cap shouldn't give a Code inspector *too* much heartburn...)

Comment: I am not touching ANYTHING at this point...XYL is HAPPY...but tnx info - if I need to have any Code inspections, will remove old plastics.